# SQL Server Object Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, objectname

I am wondering if someone can explain the concept of uniquely identifying sql server objects in a join.

In my example there are 2 schemas and 2 tables (but with same name). My assumption was that even though table name might be same between 2 schemas, as long as they are referenced with their full qualified name databasename.schemaname.objectname, SQL server should be able to make out the difference. **However that does not seem to be the case and the workaround for this is to use alias**.

I would appreciate If someone can explain or point out to some literature around **why sql server cannot uniquely identity these**.

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Sch1]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Sch2]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Sch1].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [DESC] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Sch2].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [DESC] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


Select *
From Sch1.Table_1 
Join Sch2.Table_1
    on Sch1.Table_1.Id = Sch2.Table_1.Id
```

Comment: The objects "DBA_2014.Sch2.Table_1" and "DBA_2014.Sch1.Table_1" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: Can you try your code with SQL Server 2000  or compatibility level 80?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as we are working with newer versions of SQL (2005 onwards). Thanks for the suggestion though. I wonder if schemaname in name qualification is ignored for some reason

Comment: Using aliases is not a workaround its just good practice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`SQL Server`** supports muliti-part identifiers:

```
linked_server.db_name.schema.table_name
```

In your case you have:

```
Select *
From Sch1.Table_1 
Join Sch2.Table_1
    on Sch1.Table_1.Id = Sch2.Table_1.Id
```

Now you wonder why `SQL Server` cannot differentiate between them:

```
Sch1.Table_1  != Sch2.Table_1
```

The case is because of `SQL Server` use something called **`exposed name`**.

> **exposed name**
>
> which is the **last part of the multi-part table name** (if there is no
>   alias), or alias name when present

Returning to your query you have exposed names `Table_1` and `Table_1` which are duplicates and you need to use aliases.

From **`SQL Server 2005+`**:

> Duplicate table detection algorithm has been changed correspondingly,
>   so that any tables with the same exposed names will be considered
>   duplicates

I suspect that your code could work with SQL Server 2000 but I cannot check it for sure.

For more info read **[`Msg 1013`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2007/12/21/msg-1013-the-object-s-and-s-in-the-from-clause-have-the-same-exposed-names-use-correlation-names-to-distinguish-them.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the original post. Some extra research and details in the post helped me in understanding this little more.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, I don't see any errors in your sample code. Please explain in detail what errors you're encountering.

As for the four-part naming convention. the full object name syntax is:

```
server.database.schema.object
```

So a complete usage would be, for example:

```
select * from servername.databasename.Sch1.Table_1
```

or

```
select * from servername.databasename.Sch2.Table_2
```

from which you can ignore any part as long as there is no ambiguity. Therefore in your example you can ignore severname and databasename as they are the same. But you cannot ignore schema names as they are not.

Addendum:

Based on error message you posted later, you need to employ correlation naming on the join syntax:

```
select * 
from Sch1.Table_1 as t1
inner join Sch2.Table_1 as t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: I have added the error SQL server produces for the above query in the comment

Comment: "Correlation naming". Ok, interesting SQL error message. Most everyone I know just refers to these (your t1, t2) as "table aliases", and they are indeed the fix to this problem.

Comment: @PhilipKelley alias is right, but I'm referring to the alias's purpose here, which is correlating exposed names.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Select *
    From Sch1.Table_1 x
    Join Sch2.Table_1 y
        on x.Id = y.Id
```

Does this work?